# Using static library in current project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm facing the error when I'm linking an external library and code with the current project. You will understand the problem by this example.

```
//foo.h
namespace LMS
{
    class foo
    {
        foo();         //implementation in cpp
        foo(int dummy) //implemented here
        {
            //something
        }
    };
} // namespace LMS
```

```
//foo.cpp
#include"foo.h"
namespace LMS
{
    foo::foo()
    {
        //something
    }
} // namespace LMS
```

```
//externalProgram.h
#include "foo.h"

LMS::foo *ptr;
ptr = new LMS::foo();  //Linking error: LNK 2019
ptr = new LMS::foo(2); //No error
```

Now the problem is that the external program doesn't know about the `foo.cpp` and the implementation of `class foo methods` in it. I'm currently using VS2019 and using two projects in the same solution. I've tried several ways to correct this but it didn't work out. The current way I'm seeing is to implement all the functions in header files.

EDIT: I've already linked the files!!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hopefully `foo.cpp` includes `foo.h` as well.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo in question.

Comment: After trying the simpler, rebuild all, I would start checking the actual artifacts from build of LMS to make sure the LMS.a has the right object files in it, and the object files have the right symbols.  At this point you're looking for something subtle, because on the surface it should work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue, assuming I apply some fixes: 1. Make the constructors public 2. append a semicolon to the class declaration 3. Use a `.cpp` file instead of a `.h` file for `externalProgram.h` (not how this is included otherwise) 4. Move the `new` statements to a function.

Comment: I was looking in the output tab and it was compiling all the files without any warnings or error. I was actually able to open lms.lib file, but not working in the external program

Comment: You want to see if the `lms.lib` file actually contains `foo.o` as the first point.  Then you want to see what symbols are in `foo.o`

Comment: @fabian the cpp file actually worked!!! Can you explain why it's not working in .h file?

Comment: No I cannot without more info. Assuming there is only one `.cpp` file including the header and the only contents of this file are `#include "externalProgram.h"` there shouldn't be any difference...

Comment: In the actual program, I don't have one file. I've about 10 classes with separate header and cpp files. So there may be an Issue, I'll figure it out myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mark your `externalProgram` project as dependent on the `foo` project.  This will link `foo.o` in with external program.

Using the UI you will select this in
Project > Project Dependencies : Depends on ...

If that is correct, then the problem is more subtle, sometimes just a simple typo.  At this point you want to use the command line tools to break apart the library and confirm the object files, and break apart the object files and confirm the symbols within.  A ten year old SO posting discusses using `lib.exe` to example the library file.  The dumpbin tool has a /symbols option that might also be handy for looking at the actual code generated.

Comment: Already done. I'll attach the screenshot in a minute.